# Virtual host not working AWS apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, virtualhost

I have following virtual host ( in apache2.conf file ) to load all subdomain from a single directory on AWS

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerName mydevsite.com
   ServerAlias mydevsite.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    ServerName mydevsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mydevsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It not working and subdomains are still pointing to html directory

I tried following in htaccess as well but then it gives me 500 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

My simple requirement is to load main domain from root directory and all subdomains from apps directory

Answer (score 1):

Check the Doc: [Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#using), [ServerName Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername), [ServerAlias Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.mydevsite.com
    ServerAlias mydevsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    ServerName apps.mydevsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mydevsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It points apps.mydevsite.com to apps folder only , other subdomains points to root

Comment: did you reload the conf? can you also check other conf, any other `VirtualHost` directive preceding?